# Python convert string to dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

How can I convert the string `"k:1|k1:2|k2:3|k3:4"` to a dictionary? I tried to use `split()` but I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how regular a pattern that string is, I would split the string according to the `|` character, then split each substring again according to the `:` character:

```
text = "k:1|k1:2|k2:3|k3:4"
my_dict = {}
pairs = text.split("|")
for p in pairs:
    k, v = p.split(":")
    my_dict[k] = v
```

You may want to cast `v` as an integer. Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you need :

```
>>> s = "k:1|k1:2|k2:3|k3:4"
>>> dict(i.split(':') for i in s.split('|'))
{'k': '1', 'k1': '2', 'k2': '3', 'k3': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use double split function

```
mystr = "k:1|k1:2|k2:3|k3:4"
keyval = mystr.split("|")
mydic = {}
for w in keyval:
    w = w.split(":")
    mydic[w[0]] = w[1]
print(mydic)
```

output:

```
{'k': '1', 'k1': '2', 'k2': '3', 'k3': '4'}
```